# JQuery Variable to PHP session

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

GoodDay! Is there a solution to assign a Javascript value to PHP Session.?

```
var radioVal = $(this,".margin_left25").val();
```

---

```
$_SESSION['value'] = radioVal;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix PHP and JS. You, however, can send a POST request via AJAX to the server to set this variable.

Take a look at [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Modified example from linked page:

```
$.post("test.php", { radioVal: $(this,".margin_left25").val() }, function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Then in `test.php` you can do

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['radioVal'];
```

**Alternate Method (no AJAX)**

Make a new image and set the source as your URL with your parameter.

Example:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "test.php?radioVal=" + encodeURIComponent($(this,".margin_left25").val());
```

There is no image, obviously, but it'll try to load the URL and your PHP will still execute.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will try that with window.load. . :D

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to send a request to the server, and have PHP process that request. For instance, you could use an Ajax request (in jQuery):

```
$.post("setsession.php", {"value" : $(this,".margin_left25").val();  });
```

And in `setsession.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];
```

Other ways to do this would be to submit the form, etc., but you *must* generate a request, via Ajax or otherwise, to have any interaction whatsoever between client (JavaScript) and server (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.
If you need it to set it as as session, send it via AJAX to the server, and then set it, that would work.